# IE8 div width float:right issue for responsive site

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a div, #cont3, containing another div, div.banner. #cont3 has a background image. div.banner is just a white floating div with text in it. It works everywhere but IE8 - of course. This is what it's meant to look like:

[image: How the page should render]

This is what it does in IE8:

[image: IE8 version of page]

The div doesn't float and is super-skinny. Here's the relevant html (div.container is directly within body tags):

```
<div class="container" id="cont3">
    <div class="block">     
        <div class="banner">
            <h1>Contact us</h1>
            <p>Blah blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Noto serif", serif;
  color: dimgray;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}



*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 55px;
    font-size: 3.2em;
    font-size: 350%;
    font-size: 4.5vw;
    color:  #C9494D; 
    font-family: "Noto serif", serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 3%;

}

p {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}


div.container {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

div#cont3 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/london_1920.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-behavior: url('backgroundsize.htc');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}


div#cont3 div.banner {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 70%;
    font-size: 1.1vmax; 
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 60%;
/*  height: 80%; */
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}
```

I've been fiddling with height, and adding dimensions to the parent container, as per other questions on this forum. I've also been trying to tackle the oversized headings but no joy. IE8 stubbornly makes them too big!

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this in your  and see if it works

```
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just used up all my free minutes so can't test it! But I'll try and boot up an old machine.